# Multiple Android projects all using same codebase and activities

Tags: android

I want to create several different apps/projects that all use a common code base, as well as the same activities and views. The unique things between each project would be:

- App name
- Bundle identifier
- Icon
- Version
- Analytics ID
- Web service URL
- Various images and colors

I believe this would involve creating a library project that contains the common code between projects, and then creating each project with the unique items above that reference the library project. Is this the approach I should be taking? Am I able to create all the views/activities in the library project and have the other projects use these?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, and yes. Just make sure you have a different package name for each app, and that each manifest references the activities with their full names (as they are not in the app's package)

Comment: If you use Android Studio (with gradle), you can easily do this with *flavors*.

Comment: Thank you. I've been using Eclipse with ADT. Is Android Studio now the preferred IDE for this?

Comment: @codeman from here (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) "If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates". But really, it is up to you. I think, you can use Eclipse until you will be forced to migrate to Android Studio. Use Eclipse, if this is more convenient to you )

Comment: Thank you. In your opinion, would it be easier to use Android Studio than Eclipse for what I'm trying to do? Product flavors seem pretty easy, and it looks like I could just create one project for the entire suite of apps instead of several different projects.